# Rails 4.1 ArgumentError in Episodes#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Creating an app so users can create podcasts which works but want to allow them to upload individual episode. Created a migration, model, controller   & added a partial form to allow users to add title, description of the episode but when i run this get error **ArgumentError in Episodes#new** , undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass**

extracted source

```
<div class="field">
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= t.text_field :title %>**<--Error** 
      </div>

      <div class="field">
```

application trace

```
app/views/episodes/_form.html.erb:5:in `block in _app_views_episodes__form_html_erb__2559643881136171238_70136007429400'
app/views/episodes/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_episodes__form_html_erb__2559643881136171238_70136007429400'
app/views/episodes/new.html.erb:22:in `_app_views_episodes_new_html_erb__3246403970483960928_70136007476220'
```

db migrate file

```
class CreateEpisodes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :episodes do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.references :podcast, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

episodes controller

```
    class EpisodesController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_podcast!, except: [:show]
      before_filter :require_permission
      before_action :find_podcast
      before_action :find_episode, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      def new
        @episode = @podcast.episodes.new
      end

      def show
        @episodes = Episode.where(podcast_id: @podcast).order("created_at DESC").limit(6).reject { |e| e.id == @episode.id }
      end

      def edit
      end 

      def update
        if @episode.update episode_params
          redirect_to podcast_episode_path(@podcast, @episode), notice: "Episode was succesfully updated!"
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end

      def create
        @episode = @podcast.episodes.new episode_params
        if @episode.save
          redirect_to podcast_episode_path(@podcast, @episode)
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end

      def destroy
        @episode.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
      end

      private 

      def episode_params
        params.require(:episode).permit(:title, :description, :episode_thumbnail, :mp3)
      end

      def find_podcast
        @podcast = Podcast.find(params[:podcast_id])
      end

      def find_episode
        @episode = Episode.find(params[:id])
      end

      def require_permission
        @podcast = Podcast.find(params[:podcast_id])
        if current_podcast != @podcast
           redirect_to root_path, notice: "sorry, you're not allowed to view that page"
        end
      end
    end

application controller.rb

    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
      # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
      protect_from_forgery with: :exception

      before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

      protected

      def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :title, :thumbnail)}
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password,
          :title, :thumbnail, :description, :itunes, :stitcher, :podbay)}
      end
    end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for ([@podcast, @episode]) do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :title %><br>
      <%= t.text_field :title %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :description %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :description %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :episode_thumbnail %><br>
      <%= f.file_field :episode_thumbnail %>
    </div>


    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :mp3 %><br>
      <%= f.file_field :mp3 %>
    </div>


    <%= f.submit class: "button button_highlight button_block" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ArgumentError in Episodes#new , undefined method `title' for
>   nil:NilClass

You have a typo, `<%= t.text_field :title %>` should be `<%= f.text_field :title %>`

You have to wrap the `form_helpers` with the correct `form object`.

Comment: Pavanmeister strikes again, +1 from me!